# php - variable in string

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to save a string containg a variable to another variable

```
    $bg-color = '#aaa';

    $bg_style = 'background: {$block_bg_color_top};';


    <div class="block" style="<?php echo $bg_style; ?>">

    </div>
```

I'm trying to echo the code in the style tag like this.

```
    <div class="block" style="background: #aaa;">

    </div>
```

Comment: The variable name just got displayed as it is?! That is because variable interpolation does not happen inside single-quoted strings.

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to evaluate a variable in your `background: ...` string. But variables inside single quotes aren't evaluated; they have to be in double quotes. Also, you don't need the `{` and `}` in this context. Change your code like this:

```
$bg_style = "background: $block_bg_color_top;";
```

You could also do `$bg_style = 'background: ' . $block_bg_color_top . ';';`. In this instance, the two statements are equivalent.

I'm assuming you set `$block_bg_color_top` somewhere; it's not in the code you posted. You tried to define another variable, `$block-bg`, but that is not a valid variable name, as explained below.

---

This is not strictly part of the answer, but please note that you also have a syntax error in your code. This line will result in an error:

```
$bg-color = '#aaa';
```

You will get the error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in ...

This is because `$bg-color` is not a valid variable name; it looks to the parser like you are subtracting `color` from `$bg`, but you can't assign to the result of an expression, just like you couldn't do `$x - 5 = 7;`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is the following :

```
$bg-color = '#aaa';
$bg-style = 'background: '.$bg-color;

<div class="block" style="<?php echo $bg_style; ?>">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
$bg_color = '#aaa';

$bg_style = 'background: ' . $bg_color . ';';
```